# Usage of manche, sämtliche und solche as Artikel vs Adjektive

Tags: adjective, article, adjective-ending

"Manche", "sämtliche" und "solche" können wie bestimmte Artikel (Regelfall) oder wie Adjektive (Ausnahme) verwendet werden. Die Endungen der nachfolgenden Adjektive richten sich nach der Art des Gebrauchs.

> - Manche enttäuschten Gäste beschwerten sich über das Hotel (unbestimmte Artikel)
> - Manche enttäuschte Gäste beschwerten sich über das Hotel (Artikel)

Is there any difference in meaning the two sentences or are they the same?

Comment: You seem to have a strange method to add pictures to a question in a way, that they only appear during editing but are not displayed normally.

Comment: It helps to ask your question in either English or German, not a mixture of the two. Ask in whichever language you're more comfortable with, since that will usually be the language used in the answers given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Singular: Weak.

> (Mancher schöne Weg.)

In Plural: Weak or Strong(parallel).

> (Manche schöne Wege. Manche schönen Wege.)

After "manch": Strong.

> (Manch schöner Weg)

*Manche* simply allows for weak or strong (parallel) inflection **but only in Plural**. There is no meaning difference. You have the choice to use both.

Also, the text makes a mistake and calls "manche" a "definite article" in the first paragraph. Maybe you should consider switching your learning resources if obvious mistakes like this creep in.